# Updating answers a lot

Tags: discussion, answers, editing

When writing answers I usually post the first slightly golfed version when it is working. I then proceed to golf it down further making various edits as I go. I know it is good to update as you get a better answer, but is it dis/en-couraged to make a lot of edits in a shortish time?

Comment: This is very common practice. Editing a single post a lot and frequently is not an issue at all. Just don't edit several posts in a short time (like retagging a dozen challenges), because that floods the front page.

Comment: You can see this in the posts with multiple scores with strikethroughs.

Comment: I thought this was the case but I was just making sure so that I wasn't bothering people with a lot of edits

Comment: Disallowing improvements to many answers in a short period of time because it would flood the front page demonstrates a well-designed platform and moderation system, prioritizing what matters most.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with editing your answer a bunch of times. [I've done that before](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/103051/31716), and [other high rep users](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/83276/31716) have [done that before](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/69/golf-you-a-quine-for-great-good/47112#47112).

If anything, I think these answers are more impressive, since it shows the author is not just in it for the FGITW (fastest gun in the west), but that they're very competitive and keep coming back to the answer to shave off any bytes (or [milliseconds](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/posts/74372/revisions)) they possibly can.

Comment: I think this answer is decent, but probably needs more emphasis on "not just in it for the FGITW", since your main examples were edits over a long period of time, but you haven't addressed the case in the question where this is over a "shortish time".

Comment: As someone who's FGITWed questions before now (typically ones where there's an obvious short answer which is likely impossible to outgolf, and thus the tiebreak is going to come down to submission time), FGITW answers have a ton of editing. You start off with just the program itself to discourage anyone else from posting the same program, and then repeatedly edit the post to make it prettier and/or better explained. (Sometimes you even golf off a character or two, if there's something obvious you missed; PPCG has a culture of not "sniping" an answer via fixing an obvious problem.)